# Flack Overstow - Generate spam from Stack Exchange posts

Tags: app, python, obsolete

> ### Online demo courtesy of Nathan Osman:
>
> http://quickmediasolutions.com/flack
>
> **Note:** this tool now works with all Stack Exchange sites. Just paste the URL of your profile and the app will take care of the rest.

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

> `$ python flack.py 126042`
>
> `Before 'if' statement... Past 'if' statement. Floating point exception on my system. So, you should check whether e is a very popular way to access Word and Excel documents. There's a line inside an expression like that; the simplest workaround is to end of the using block } If someone really wants to access it as an "anonymous" stub directly generated by the framework, for simplicity's sake. Check our Eureqa, a free (as in beer) utility from Cornell University. What's particularly interesting about Eureqa is a dereferenced pointer. If you had done var quux = GetSomething() where I've seen it, but I remember their variable context, and are full Warnings turned on. When -cw is customary in Lua to start arrays while those around are willing to Integer (I suspect there is and double parentheses also prints out 10, but running that through ruby -cw is used to Check the syntax.`

### About

Flack Overstow is a toy, written in Python 2.6 (but *should* be compatible with 2.5 -- let me know if it's not). It pulls the latest questions or answers or comments for a given user ID and creates a [Markov chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Markov_text_generators) of the text, then gives you something that should never be posted as a real answer. (If you're not familiar, Markov chains are one way that spammers make emails/posts that look like natural text, until you look more closely.)

#### License

It's a toy application, so I chose the [MIT license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) to make it very open source.  Feel free to include it on your site or in your application. If you do use it, you aren't obligated to tell me about it, but I'd love to hear about it or see your application.

#### Download

My [Bazaar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar_%28software%29) branches are on [Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Emark.rushakoff/flackoverstow/0.1), but you can download the package (it's just three Python files in a single zip file or [tarball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29)) from [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/flackoverstow/downloads/list).

#### Platform

I've successfully run this on both Windows and Mac platforms. I would expect it to run fine on Linux as well.

### Contact

If you need to contact me for some reason, use [Launchpad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchpad_%28website%29) or Google Code for it. Or just comment here.

### Code

Flack Overstow is written in pure Python 2.6 and uses [`simplejson`](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.1.1/docs/index.html) when possible, then falls back to [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html). It depends on Beautiful Soup to get rid of HTML in the body portion of questions, answers, comments.

### Your Flack Overstows

If you generate any particularly funny spam with Flack Overstow, post it in a chatroom somewhere, **not here.**  We want to keep our posts focused and on topic for the hosting site.

You can play with the options on the command line (`flack.py --help` for details). You can change the length of the Markov chains (number of words in a chain), how many chains to use to make a post, which site to use, and more. You can specify an API key to use at the command line, if necessary.

#### Updates in v0.2

I've updated the API version to use v1.0, and I've modified the command line format for specifying the site.  Previously you had a couple fixed choices, but now you have to specify the whole domain (e.g. `stackoverflow.com` instead of just `stackoverflow`) -- but this means you can now use Flack Overstow on other Stack Exchange sites.

Have fun!

Comment: Hilarious! But as soon as I see one of these get posted on StackOverflow, this gets a downvote.

Comment: @George: Jon Skeet will still undoubtedly get upvotes if and when he posts the following: Fundamentally can't make DoSomeMagic() work with the string might change in future, but you don't want it to be pretty much a one-liner. I'm not on my current installation... that may have a rogue character at the resource names, I'd just do something similar. You can't do this at version 2.0, service packs notwithstanding. More efficiently (O(n)): int count = ID.Count; for (int i = 0; i.

Comment: Even though this is for fun and not a serious application, this is fantastic!!!

Comment: Yay! Launchpad! :)

Comment: I get an error when I execute flack.py: `"BeautifulSoup required to format data"`

Comment: @George: That's documented in the `Code` heading of the post.  The only thing it's doing is converting HTML entities to text... I haven't done a terrible amount of research on it, but I'd be open to a replacement, as long as it can convert whatever entities are thrown at it.

Comment: @Mark: Please consider listing Flack Overstow on [StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/).

Comment: @Kevin Montrose, @Mark Rushakoff: with api version 0.9 gone, the script is broken; however, it Works just as well with 1.0, you just need to change the version in `grabber.py` on line 36 (and I can't push that change to Launchpad).

Comment: this needs some update lovin' -- Mark?

Comment: @Jeff: I haven't been online much lately.  I'll put some effort into updating the API version, and I don't think I'll host it on Launchpad anymore either.  More likely to be Google Code, perhaps over my lunch break today.

Comment: @Jeff: Please see the update I wrote at the top of the question.

Comment: @Mark: Oh please don't! I like Launchpad!

Comment: @Jeff and @George:  I've updated the downloads on Google Code so that it uses API version 1.0, and so that you can specify any Stack Exchange site.  I'm having trouble with SSH here at work, so I'll update Launchpad from home sometime in the near future.

Comment: @Mark: Great! Question... would it be possible to somehow support Python 2.4 with this application? With a bit of hacking and tweaking, I was able to get it working in Python 2.4 (you can even try it out on my website using the link I put in your question above). The reason I ask is because it would be awesome if I could keep up to date with your releases simply by copying the files to my website - which unfortunately is stuck using Python 2.4.

Comment: @Mark: **Also,** if maintaining the project on Launchpad is too hard, I would be glad to join the project and patch a few things here and there. Before I forget, we created a chat room for no other reason than posting funny things from this app - transcript [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/515).

Comment: @George: I've put the updated code on https://code.launchpad.net/~mark.rushakoff/flackoverstow/0.2 ... I'm having issues with bzr/launchpad.  I'd like to add you as an authorized user to the project (can't find the option), or at least maybe get the github equivalent of a pull request from you.  Failing that, can I get a diff patch from you for the 2.4 fixes?

Comment: @Mark: I think you need to create a team to enable access to multiple users.

Comment: http://quickmediasolutions.com/flack/ seems broken (gives 404 on my machine)

Comment: @mark I've installed `BeautifulSoup4` and I keep getting `BeautifulSoup required to format dataTry 'easy_install beautifulsoup'` when I try to run it on `http://scifi.stackexchange.com/`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Pureferret It's been a long time since I've done anything in Python.  Have you tried using regular `beautifulsoup` instead of `beautifulsoup4`?  Their home page implies that they might not be cross-compatible.

Comment: I just tried it on my meta profile http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/161467/george-duckett but it appears to only be using my (only) answer, not questions too. Is this correct?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett You can pass the `-t` option to specify questions or answers or comments.  I'm pretty sure you can only do one at a time though.

Comment: 'Only server-side code is something I don't trust' while THE entire point of that answer was to say that only server-side code is safe. (Assuming a potential attacker doesn't have your FTP credentials). Brilliant!

Comment: My favourite is from [Mi Yodeya](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=7604207#7604207), where I've posted very little so it doesn't have much to work with: "Christianity SE is very much true to its mission of being a variety of Jewish opinion."

Comment: First sententie I get (from SO): `Be executed.` Well, I'd like to live on for a bit actually.

Comment: This is terrific. My favorite quote from Meta is: `YES use WordPress`

Comment: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/389/formatting-sandbox/4661#4661.

Comment: Dude! We can totally automate ISP tech support! "Now renew your DHCP password from the Ethernet cable by pressing the reset button with a pin for 15 seconds. When you receive a confirmation email, we will transfer you tier 2 support. Have I answered your nice day!"

Comment: My favourite single line comes from Mi Yodeya: "[Christianity SE is very much true to its mission of being a variety of Jewish opinion.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=7604206#7604206)"

Comment: It appears that API 2.0 broke this app before I even knew about it. So very sad.

Comment: How do you do this?

Comment: From my profile on mechanics.SE: "Then take a fingernail brush and scrub the stain - especially if you're rolling down hill. Bottom line: You have to press the brake."

Comment: awww `There was an error retrieving the Flack for the specified profile.` my profile won't be taken.

Comment: Also getting @Tschallacka's error. Looks like something broke.

Comment: Can I use Flack Overstow to generate *rude or abusive* content?

Comment: There are a lot of things that don't work. First of all, in Python 3, there have to be parentheses with `print`. It was easy enough to edit the source files to add those, but then it said it couldn't find `urllib2` and `StringIO`. I tried to remove those `import` lines. Then it gave me an error saying ``BeautifulSoup required to format dataTry `easy_install beautifulsoup` ``. I tried `easy_install beautifulsoup`, but that apparently doesn't work with Python 3. So I searched on the web and tried `easy_install beautifulsoup4`, but that didn't get the error about `dataTry` to disappear.

Comment: Also on the website, I get the same error as Tschallacka and jpmc26. I have no idea what's causing that, but it might be Python 3 again.

Comment: Now make it post the result as a question using the SE API (just kidding).

Answer (score 151):

This is just plain awesome! I could go on with this all day. Here are some of "my" quotes (from Meta):

- Now go and spread the hyperlink
- You could provide your community with Gravatar and Stack Overflow.
- the `<center>` cannot receive answers.
- New users are strongly discouraged from scanning an analog source. For one unit translates to another.
- I want to turn off the computer for now and I can't find the same information. At least that's fine, just do it.
- Alexa considers their statistics to prove anything. Thus, beyond any software out there that is smart about the layout of the site. Shudder.
- If a question receives 15 downvotes and no upvotes, chances are pretty high that it's a side effect of a paragraph break.

Comment: I have to upvote for the last one

Comment: Yeah, the first bunch were pretty funny, but I actually laughed out loud for the last one :)

Comment: The last one is **awesome**!!!

Comment: Wow - you've created a Sarah Palin interview answer generator !

Comment: -1 Wow, thanks a lot, you almost made me choke on my pizza and die. And when a moderator (@George) uses 3 exclamation marks, you can tell something's terribly wrong. :)

Comment: Oh my god, I can't stop laughing

Comment: the `<center>` cannot receive answers :D

Comment: The third one comes from the `The <center> cannot hold` meme.

Comment: On my first pass, I read "side effect of a paragraph leak" and fell off my chair.

Answer (score 30):

As requested, here are some good ones I got on Stack Overflow from my posts:

- Turns out that the problem was that hair-pulling just because I was using Doxygen comments in your source code, you can easily generate documentation in Python.
- In the application. This is where failures and diagnostic information should totally drop that and try jQuery.
- Python is a manageable-sized block of data to work with. You prevent malicious 4GB POST requests.
- I haven't tried this, but you may be able to remove many of the sections, but these could not as difficult as it sounds and can be quite rewarding.
- The dll contains headers, exports, and such things that make it completely impossible to do.
- Okay, so it seems like the problem is a great library for generating PDF files with PHP.
- My personal opinion is: INFO - and the one I use in certain cases, is to do it.
- Seriously though, I reccomend extensive customization of the other answers. A solution, though - and the one I don't know...
- As for learning new languages/frameworks, you make no mention mixed ASCII and Unicode characters

And my new favorite:

- DEBUG - information related to internal processes or emacs.

Comment: The "try jQuery" could be added at the end of all the generated posts. This would be close to the reality.

Comment: my personal opinion is INFO too! lol

Comment: "Okay, so it seems like the problem is a great library for generating PDF files with PHP." I'm pretty sure the problem is just PHP. ;)

Answer (score 23):

Some funny ones from Stack Overflow:

- a good IDE can then write a Java file that a common cause of segfaults is harder to monitor/troubleshoot
- Use Java's resource loader to load the image file between processes by passing around the code from the SVN repo.
- This setup also helps out API consumers, and is a code smell in the Sun/Oracle JRE

*Sounds like I hate Java.*

Super User:

- Further, Safely Remove provides an XML API *XML solves everything.*
- To switch back to your graphical X session you want to reverse-engineer the app. *Never realized it's that hard.*
- If your USB drive is NTFS-formatted, Linux's ntfs-3g is usually unable to warn if text is not present; you could use this with "please". *Oh, he's using the [Intercal](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=INTERCAL&oldid=499054247#Control_structures) shell!*
- It's possible that the archive contains files several times. Obviously more laborious.
- Another possibility is that you have installed the OS kernel. The kernel can register its own interrupt handlers, which can cause problems. *OSs are more trouble than they're worth. Real programmers write in [real mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode).*
- It will then warn you for the rest of the command line of each process to type commands at the command-line: *Most helpful warning ever.*

Meta:

- To do.
- Will silently mess this up, displaying a narwhal.
- We should complain to Oracle that they messed up by default so people will only find them if they're looking for the rest of the community. *Java again...*

English:

- In people of [[Scandinavia]]n extraction there is a rat plutonium, it will soon die of radiation poisoning. *COMMA SPLICE*
- I have been retained in caricatures, especially in the elevator.
- There is no consensus among the standards bodies, but that's not from inherent offensiveness

Linguistics:

- Article "My Client Is Using Non-English Sounds! A Tutorial in Advanced Phonetic Transcription Part III: Prosody and Unattested Sounds" also discusses the extIPA (and does not list this diacritic. The article "My Client Is Using Non-English Sounds! A Tutorial in Advanced Phonetic Transcription Part III: Prosody and Unattested Sounds" also discusses the extIPA (and does not list this diacritic. The article "My Client Is Using Non-English Sounds! A Tutorial in Advanced Phonetic Transcription Part III: Prosody and Unattested Sounds" also discusses the extIPA (and does not list the diacritic). The paper also describes a non-IPA system (VoQS) for indicating phonation of stretches of the claim that there's a distinction between /VV/ (within a morpheme) and Unattested Sounds" also discusses the extIPA (and does not list the diacritic).
- The survival of perception. *Profound, but what does it mean?*
- Ergo, some languages have more speakers than others. *That requires proof!*

Comment: The survival of perception. Profound, but what does it mean?
Ergo, some languages have more speakers than others. That requires proof! both hilarious

Comment: "We should complain to Oracle that they messed up by default so people will only find them if they're looking for the rest of the community." Not Java, that's their database.

Answer (score 21):

Mine:

- The fix is a programming language: CSS becomes a fully bloated format with stuff I wrote in a recent project because realplayer uses DoPlay() instead of Play().
- Instead, I've experimented until I've come up what to fix. At least it's better than hammering F5.
- You should warn the user before he begins using the system.
- I'm very happy to confirm the obvious
- I believe I can only handle 1 text-shadow.
- This baby generates an idea that may not be applicable in all contexts.
- You should be parseable with relative ease. However, this is: Awkward.
- Also, you may want a website I make one. (* Other formats avaliable)
- I'm seriously annoyed by whatever string you want.
- Think of! It can be numbers or later.
- @sebastian's fix may not support anti-aliasing depending on its age.
- Be warned it will be your friends! :)
- Oh and if I want a website I think this should be used mostly.

Answer (score 18):

Oh, hilarious!

Here are some of mine from AskUbuntu:

- there is just a relatively small amount of apps that may or may not include a cartoon.
- From my experience it shouldn't be aware that it is a pretty advanced tool.
- You always trust Amazon. (*Yeah sure..*)
- Ok, In the window that pops up, copy and paste the following: [Desktop Entry] Type=Application Name=Minecraft Comment=Click here to play well with AMD cards (*Appearantly, I created a fix for AMD users*)
- Microsoft doesn't run a desktop environment by default, and doesn't have many desktop apps you probably don't need anyway.
- You must now reboot your privacy
- download the download.. Please try to install the internet.

**Edit: Just came accross this one.. xD**

But anyway.. since your computer came preïnstalled with Windows 8, there is a link with instructions how to live

Comment: `download the download.. Please try to install the internet.` oh my god, these are amazing

Comment: UVed for the last one.

Answer (score 16):

This thing is so hilarious. I love it. Here are some generations [from AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/134848/jop):

- Open the Software Sources application. Go to the Additional Drivers tab. Choose the closed source driver for your hard-drive, the chance of possibility you need it for some reason, but it's not that easy to install instead of Windows (WARNING: THE LATTER WILL DELETE ALL YOUR FILES STORED IN WINDOWS!!!).
- Kubuntu is a version of Ubuntu icon in the topleft corner and you will love it.
- So you are being worked upon.
- Then click the "Recommended Repair" button and wait until it's basicly both a perfume tester and applications.
- Click Partition > Resize/Move At "New size", lower the number with the "Select boot device" button on the largest one) by dragging it's edge to fill the whole drive and a menu should appear that asks if you want to try Ubuntu and you will love it.
- The Java browser plugin will also find relative forum link where you can post queries.
- Try using your computer NOW!
- Wait a moment and a menu should appear that asks if you are setting up a trading system using that machine as a server?
- Every time you turn on your PC, turn your PC off
- You will get installed.

Comment: "Every time you turn on your PC, turn your PC off" This is the most zen thing I have ever seen.

Comment: from my SU: Up. Speaking of which, have a good Linux user friend available to help to use a pen-drive form of Ubuntu or Kubuntu to evaluate it the way you want it.

Comment: speaking of up, lol

Comment: "Try using your computer NOW!" is a perfect ending to a troll answer which destroyed your system.

Answer (score 15):

- This example uses C operators, but they are also used for WinNT/2000/XP/Vista/7
- Additionally, `new ImageIcon("image.png").getImage()` can be used to load a C++ header file with functions that it is not.
- However, the value returned by `Distance()` will be truncated to an `ImageIcon(byte[])` constructor, and compare the number to the minimum and maximum values for each range. Iterate through all of the ranges and minimum and maximum values for Win9x.
- If you do anything you will be interrupted frequently.
- Consider creating an alias such as battery to reboot a couple of times.
- Change your username, then logout and log back in as your graphics card, hard drives, memory, etc.
- Programs usually consist of thousands or millions of operating systems.
- The man command is because they think it will be accessed with the man command.
- Newly elected officials have to learn quite a whimsical, and foolish country.
- Foreign relations might come to dislike our country and cease voting.
- A good way to make sure you multiply polynomials in binary, is to form a table of Greek letters and their approximate equivalents, which you may find interesting.

Comment: “The man command is because they think it will be accessed with the man command.” So true…

Comment: "Programs usually consist of thousands or millions of operating systems." That's terrifying

Answer (score 15):

I realize this is rather old, but I thought someone might get a laugh out of some of these:

**Ask Ubuntu:**

- A Happier Update The problem now seems to lie with the new kernel.
- You should (according to what I find) be considered closed, methinks.
- Was there any special reason you wanted to use this site?
- Hahaha. the meaning is the opposite. What is going on with quality control in UBuntu? They are ruining the prestige of Linux.

*Note: I did **NOT** say that last sentence.  Must have come from someone elses comment*

- The Lord of Time solved this in the Accessibility settings.
- The config file Lets open up the prestige of Linux.
- So if you want to create the new kernel. It won't recognize my problem was I never ran update-grub.
- So right now, I'm rebooting with a .
- If you would still like to be used manually you will need to know what the name or disable the bluetooth indicator
- All Debian based distros in general) use xbindkeys -k to find the name when installing a package
- The dash is what you're looking for. See also: What's the right terminology for Unity's UI elements? If you hope into a

**MSO**

- That's why the wording is: This question already has because it's just links to the 95% sense? No.
- I'd argue that closing (again most) of Long Tail Programming Questions: I think this still applies.
- SO: Since we (almost) all as off-topic individually.

**Chess Beta**

- I also found a Windows port. That goes into the subject on page 5.
- There is hardly any master we know who cannot play at least one or two?
- The program Winboard has a neat flash based interface, though most people believe that it doesn't harm your health.
- In 1930 the USSR banned displays a chessboard on the screen, accepts moves made with the mouse, and Capablanca Chess.

Comment: The second-last one is a gem!

Comment: Actually you kind of did (you posted a quote) http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/353669

Answer (score 14):

Here are some of the best snippets I've seen so far.

From Stack Overflow,

- You should be downloaded.
- `Me.load`.
- the given URL actually points to a coincidence.
- Dolby also specifies that the conversion may say your password is being over amp'd by 41.4%.
- The server/client then downloads the author.
- leave out advanced features like this until you find your programs name.
- this code may be an array.

From Meta Stack Overflow,

- the user is undescriptive, clearly it's very ambiguous, and overall just unhelpful.
- Lets face it, the site does need to be displayed.
- I'd also suggest that posts should definitely be implemented.
- a user posts a user.
- Burnination Completed! Burnination Completed! Burnination Completed!
- searching rather than asking is the current UI trend.
- I'd say it's unnecessary to add a user.
- Mods, the poor little suckers.
- Damn, now you have to search both MSO and MSE.

Comment: "the given URL actually points to a coincidence." Surprise! "leave out advanced features like this until you find your programs name." Like what, printing version information? ... all the MSO ones are amazing.

Answer (score 11):

- Explanation of the uppercase and lowercase letters (specifically [, \, ], ^, _, `).
- `innerHTML` is not a regex like this: `\D(\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{3})\D` `\D` will be automatically escaped for you.
- You use this method, the text will be 2 as well.
- If you use this is the case, try a regex for this: `String yourString = "<210>;`
- On to say that `$result` is false
- Explanation of where it used to be.
- If it is 3 again, so the dash gets added.

**And my favorites:**

- # ask for the word, #.
- Test is not.
- If this is the .0 is at the end, so the dash gets added.
- Through all the numbers from 0 to one variable!

**Finally, the most amusing of all: meta:**

> Rep on a site for it to have over 200 rep on a suggested edit, and I was typing a custom "reject" message. However, by the time I finish typing, I am trying to foo a bar, but it is throwing a foobar error. Instead of I am trying to foo a bar, but it has nothing to do with actually programming, it is just about the post is not reviewable. (click image to enlarge) If it hasn't already a synonym of performance, so this tag should be too. Escape a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times. Answering an old question bumps it up to the top of 5 or more. This badge can use "Large blocks of code with a baz, but it is throwing a foobar error. EDIT: I am using a baz. Isn't the first?

I also got these in an otherwise boring paragraph:

- Bounties are noise and make the post harder to read.
- C is programming, and sometimes over three years.

(code formatting added by me)

Answer (score 10):

```
# Heap of (non-prime, prime factor) tuples.
Todel = [ (4, 2) ]
n = 3
while True:
  if all(candidate in text for text in commands[:]:
    if "rm " in cmd:
      commands.remove(cmd)
```

Just compile and disassemble your architecture on your specific build of `dis` by calling `dis.dis(f1)`, here is the Windows API

you might want to give defaults for instance variables in your constructor I would however do this:

```
class Foo:
  def init(num = None):
    self.num = num if and only if you are dealing with immutable types!)

class Foo:
  def random_zeroes(max_size):
    "Create a list of zeros for a random size (up to the end of the line as iterable
  except TypeError, e:
    #object is documented in the sort man page for "The Great Adventures of Jack Smith"?
```

The 2% of your userbase probably noticed the issue in the Python Shell window, choose Debugger from them, you can have lists of.

Comment: That's a shame the code doesn't compile :)  I wonder if there would be a good way to retain formatting... Right now I just compress all whitespace to a single space, as you probably have noticed.

Answer (score 10):

Arqade has a lot of potential for this, here are some of mine:

- Dead is especially fun to use.
- The process requires a lot of Monuments after you buy EotN for the player who got the final hit, and only if it was gathered from rather than destroying it, so it needs to be done at time of activation.
- For example, I currently have a streetpass team that is strong enough to provide an updated answer.
- These are simply novelty weapons. They are located together, and all European servers are located together, and all European servers are located together, so the back.
- The game should have come with a leaflet that has the second highest melee damage.
- There is no one in the language that you're most profitable option.
- Your best bet is to run for your life.

Update: Here are a few from Stack Overflow:

- It turns out that the option actually converted my project to a negative number.
- You want to have a back button from the new UITabBarController to the device.
- If that is not the problem (as in my case), it is likely that you don't have a local knowledge.
- If you want an individual view's rotation to behave differently than or equal to zero, you simply cast it as NSUInteger.
- How does the loop continue beyond the actual length of the array? Because you will.

Comment: Dead is especially fun to use. /For example, I currently have a streetpass team that is strong enough to provide an updated answer./Your best bet is to run for your life./ the first and last one are the funniest yet!! Can I steal them?? ahahaha

Comment: Haha, go ahead.

Comment: Yeah, I'll get the Collector's Edition, which has a leaflet with the *highest* melee damage.

Answer (score 10):

Some of my own "quotes" from Stack Overflow:

- I know, there is no way to explain the way Python treats variables and parameters.
- This will remove all characters on Earth.
- I modified the function and now it's just "Hello World!".
- So yes, it's neither a xls file nor a text editor is like opening a SMTP server through a HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 8):

These are my favorites on Meta Stack Exchange:

- the bounty will be the best advice and you may find yourself in rough seas. Not?
- Then you have uploaded your image to delete incorrect answers
- Meta Stack Overflow is self-promotion, and it doesn't add any value to the answer.

And on Code Golf:

- the byte array actually have NO idea how it works
- Then, you prompt for sharing great improvements!

On Meta Stack Overflow:

- Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they get review-banned to avoid bad reviews.

Comment: O! Uploading images deletes answers? *When did they add this?!*

Answer (score 6):

In .NET 2.0, and you'll benefit a file is changed, that's not possible to do this using JavaScript and a font that isn't fixed-width... it doesn't have special rules in terms of what expressions you can pass the result to `setTimeout`, you want to get only the minutes and constrain the generic type to those types that implement `IComparable`, then use a switch in the general

```
        case '001/':
        case '002/':
            $arrayMobile[] = $item;
            break;
    }
}
```

If you have another `Sub` that contains the common logic, and call that from both bits are the same, `1` if either one bit OR the other `!` negates it again. A concise cast to boolean. It's pretty much better in VB.NET) but if they're different). 1 Actually, it's n modulo 32. `1 >> 32` is `1`. For example, here's `5 | 3: 5 = 101 3 = 011 | ----- 111 = 7` And loop through it as follows:

```
$.each(data, function(index, option) {
    options += '<option value="' + option.value + '">' + '\\b', 'g'), 'this.' + declaredVariable[1]);
} // This is the prototype!
```

You can call any function like that functionality for just about anything. Firefox adds some extra padding. You can actually run. The CLR is pretty much equivalent to `Boolean(options.guess)`. What it gives a nice, clean MVC feel. It's probably easiest to just abstract your hash-cracker method out: `Function hashType(ByVal filename As String) As Boolean`

If there's an icon at `/favicon.ico`, use objects. `row_array()` then. But consider objects. They prepend the position of the script sometime after the entire DOM manipulations, not HTML:

```
var list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(Dictionary<string, string> dict in dictionariesToCombine) {
    foreach(var item in the list
```

, so the list gets shorter, and your original count is the length, not the ending index. Pass 12 instead of 24. echo.

Comment: Pass 12 instead of 24. echo. Roger that! hahaha

Comment: So... no changes to JS files not using a monospace font? LOL :D

Answer (score 3):

Here are some from my answers on SuperUser:

- Remedies Here are some actual reasons why an application developer felt that Dalvik was released (or maybe the race condition still exists, and you're just really!)
- In theory, you could write C/C++ or even assembly code if your page file is heavily utilized due to RAM pressure.
- The default behavior of Windows is in text: Find what: (.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+) Replace dialog, tick Regular expression, and enter the above expressions. Here it is still slower than RAM by orders of magnitude.
- Having your page file on an SSD will help, but it will also wear out the contents of the connection.
- There's no simple way to generalize that won't work in your situation for the respective platform.
- If the total input power is greater than 2 TB capacity if you have open, or upgrading to a user has accidentally deleted lots of any that do, off the top of the kernel ABI Database server for data mining, which is very little that separates Dalvik from Objective-C, .NET, Ruby, the Oracle Hotspot JVM, or the Java programming language syntax is responsible for high power consumption.
- Occasionally, you might encounter a Pentium 4 architecture from 2004 is running.
- This will help for details.
- If the verification tool tells you sent a message through the bus, the CPU wouldn't be there on your computer.
- You probably need the program, just remove it.
- It is very badly hosed, you may have more than one operating system installed in its firmware.
- On top of all this, this VBA solution: IMHO that for reasons of safeguarding your data this is running, and provide that as output here, along with the output of RAM for a desktop or laptop battery will take whatever scraps are unable to get it to satisfy your needs.
- If the data in there isn't critical to your parser by giving up if you may have to delete the database and re-initialize it from scratch; be discussing programming techniques. (in my mind I imagined a concerned mother saying, "*yall better be discussing programming techniques when I get home!!!*")
- If it's there, look inside of it for a last-ditch effort, you can try reinstalling Windows, then install your programs one of the programs you normally use Task Scheduler; it could be using sudo mount, then fsck that volume, running the appropriate fsck command to charge both the laptop battery and the core of Android web browsers (both Firefox and Chrome) are written to.

Answer (score 3):

**These all come from my mechanics.stackexchange profile.**

> There's a post here: whatconsumer.co.uk whose top post seems to be burning an over-rich fuel mixture.

Hmm, I wonder what they're running *their* servers on.

> Use a sponge with some water in it to disconnect the battery, it doesn't harm on the engine or the transmission

Well, I hope not!

> Great question! There do not appear to be any manufacturers who are putting them in your face and on your arms.

Hrmph!  Commercialism these days is so *in your face!*

> The operation of the vehicle with only the handbrake is a big jump, but not likely extremely damaging, in my opinion. However, mistreating it can be so simple that it may well croak before you stop, but there is no real reason to replace it

I suppose not.  If the brakes croak before you stop, you won't have to replace *them*, you'll have to replace *the car!*

> When a car is cranking badly, there may be a couple landmines hidden on the property somewhere.

Um, yeah.  Smart car.

> As others have already stated, washer fluid will not burn correctly, and will cause carbon deposits on the plugs.

Really?  I have a hard time believing it will leave anything on the spark plugs... except washer fluid, of course.

#### And my absolute favorite:

> When you're driving on wet pavement or a diy type of person. If nothing's moving down there, nothing can.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade isn't necessary for your problem. Just switch to Ubuntu Classic from the /app folders: [Icon Theme] Name=Faenza Humanity Inherits=ubuntu-mono-dark,humanity,hicolor Comment=Custom Faenza + Humanity Theme for Jorge Castro Directories=apps/16,apps/22,apps/24,apps/32,apps/48,apps/scalable [apps/16] Size=16 Context=Apps Type=fixed [apps/22] Size=22 Context=Apps Type=fixed [apps/48] Size=48 Context=Apps Type=fixed [apps/scalable] Size=96 Context=Apps Type=Scalable MinSize=64 MaxSize=128 Now select the new theme in gnome-appearance-properties. Delete the file: ~/.local/share/mime/mime.cache, and it should just be pushed upstream, but are looking for. For the wireless, remove the gnome-panel package, but I wouldn't suggest removing anything else for now. Better safe than sorry. When you are using the same service as a Live installation though. Emesene 2 was only recently (rushed to release) released. For this reason a lot around the subject at hand without editing the source for Unity and to my knowledge, the plugin has to patch GNOME applications, or third party developers have to create replacements, that honestly should just be pushed.

Comment: Lemme guess... askubuntu.com?

Comment: @muntoo yes :)!

Answer (score 1):

> Outside world until the constructor returns.
>
> If the native library/code cannot be linked to by that JVM (for
>   example, if you have a Windows JVM (for example, if you have a rich
>   history of cross-platform support on runtimes like Mono.
>
> You may like to pose a few more possible for readability.
>
> Instead of declaring ProductOfDouble at the top and then setting
>   fields to default values. Evaluating arguments to the constructor are
>   evaluated, left-to-right.
>
> If any of the argument evaluations completes abruptly, any argument
>   expressions to work up an example at your else block to give netPay a
>   32-bit JVM and 64-bit library), then that program must be open-source
>   and boxing, while ar.remove(0); affects that list without creating a
>   new copy of the units digit (modulo), which is an assignment due to
>   the = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
>
> From Date javadoc: Deprecated.
>
> As each new field instance is created, it is initialized to its
>   default?

Comment: "Outside world until the constructor returns." bliss.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few funny ones from Code Golf (with a bit of markdown salted on it):

- Port of the function $f$, please leave a trailing space.
- For example, if you ran it through the server console, you realise that it adds 100 to ceilingcat for another 2 bytes shaved off by using puts instead of the fractions representing both numbers (with an integer numerator).
- Vyxal, 6 characters `ø⟇Ė0›+` `ø⟇` gets the first website's request is finished!
- Explanation (might need to scroll) `f=lambda *a:a[0] # ‎⁡Make a function that returns the correct sum.` But if you realise that it adds 100 to add at least one character.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Apps! The question says *If you generate any particularly funny spam with Flack Overstow, post it in a chatroom somewhere, not here. We want to keep our posts focused and on topic for the hosting site.* I know that means many answers here should be deleted, but it's better not to post new ones.