# Is Stack Apps the place to suggest applications?

Tags: discussion, meta, app-request

Is StackApps.com the place to suggest applications you would like to see created?

I sometimes receive suggestions along the lines of *"Is it possible add [feature-suggestion] to Stack Exchange?"* I send most feature requests to meta.stackoverflow but some suggestions seem more appropriate for a custom software application.

Is it appropriate for end-users to come here with suggestions for applications to be created?

Comment: Here is a question I started already a while back: https://stackapps.com/questions/121/what-ideas-do-you-have-for-the-api

Comment: great question. now we just need to stick a cattle prod in jeff and get him to start a dialog about making stackapps approriate for both end-users and devs.

Answer (score 7):

My humble opinion: given that all the App/API devs are here, it makes sense to post app suggestions here.  Might create a new "app-request" tag.

Comment: +1 for the *app-request* tag suggestion - this should become a regular featured tab alongside the [apps](http://stackapps.com/?tab=apps) tab, actually, to get Stack Apps into the desired and logical direction of being the Stack Exchange app store, as @code poet and others are correctly advocating, unfortunately somewhat at odds with the [Stack Exchange Pantheon](http://stackapps.com/questions/959) right now, [apparently](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/55163/area-51-site-proposal-stackexchange-api-application-development/55171#55171) ;)

Comment: I just submitted a respective [feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/55807/could-the-app-request-tag-be-made-an-official-one-and-featured-on-the-front-page), hope you don't mind - as mentioned there your cool tag name really pin pointed the issue at hand!

Answer (score 4):

YES!

This is the perfect place to suggest an idea for an application.

Now, if you suggest an application idea and I implement it, do you have any IP claim?

There are all kinds of people in the world and you just have to expect that someone is going to raise a fuss of one kind or another regarding IP, but that just comes with the territory I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

If you think that the requested feature is best for a custom app and not a general feature for a site send them here.

There are lots of devs here just waiting to jump on a great new idea.

(That's my not humble opinion.)